# Настройка NGINX для api swagger

Tags: nginx, docker, swagger

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть докер с NGINX в нем настроен проект. Есть ли возможность настроить NGINX, чтобы он обрабатывал не только https://example.com/api, а https://example.com/jshfsh/api, https://example.com/jshfsh/jfldjkfgl/api, т.е. https://example.com/*/api

В данный момент настроено так:

```
location /api {
                proxy_pass  http://example.com:8080/api;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Пробовал настройку и подобные регулярные выражения, решения не нашел

```
location ^~ /api/ {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поправьте на

```
location  ~ ^.*/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass   http://example.com:8080/api/$1;      
}
```

Документация nginx https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Сервис в котором можно онлайн проверить свою конфигурацию https://nginx.viraptor.info/

Comment: я пробовал такой вариант, но после него выдает такую ошибку 
"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except"

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Кстати, если бы вам нужно было обращаться к одному enpoint, то можно было бы указать без regex: `location jshfsh/api { rewrite ^.*$ /api break;`

Comment: не к одному, а к любому сгенерированному (*/api/), т.е. чтобы nginx производил поиск до первого /api, и когда найдет проксировал на ':8080/api'

Comment: Обновленный ответ помог, благодарю!